# IE8 and 9 :hover issue on dropdown menu

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, navigation, hover, internet-explorer-9

We've recently updated our site with some new navigational elements.

The nav is freaking out on IE8 and 9.

Here's the link: http://theunlimited.co.za/

I can see that the psuedo :hover element is on the li and know that IE prefers or requires it on the anchor tag.

Comment: seems like a margin/padding problem, IE just can't understand things right. Try a different css for IE with less padding/margin.

Answer (score 1):

Add This css Class

```
 .submenu { top: 22px !important; }
```